# Spark Dataframe.write() completed percentage

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a Dataframe to a file. As the data frame is quite large, I want to know what is the status of the write operation in terms of **Progress percentage**, because it continues execution for a good amount of time.

```
myDataFrame
    .filter(myFilter)
    .write
    .json(ExportPath)
```

Is there any way to know the percentage of data written to file?
Or at least get the number of partitions that have completed individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick manual check, you can check the processed amount of data in the [Spark UI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#web-interfaces). For a more automated way of accessing the data, either the [REST API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) or the [Metrics library](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#metrics) is helpful.